# Multiple bibliography/addbibresource in reftex

Tags: biblatex, emacs, auctex, subdividing, reftex

It seems that reftex only scans the file associated with the first bibliography/addbibresource command:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,url=false, isbn=false,
            doi=false, backref=true,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{a.bib}
\bibliography{b.bib}
```

only entries in `a.bib` are suggested when using `C-[`. Is it a bug or am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question seems to be more *auctex-related* than *TeX-related*, isn't it?

Comment: @LudovicC. StackOverflow moves AUCTeX-related questions here, TeX Stack Exchange moves AUCTeX-related questions there, there should be an AUCTeX Stack Exchange site `:-)`.  @Marc it seems you're right, I will try to dig into this problem.

Comment: @giordano Sure we can have a look at the AUCTeX part but I would have thought that this would fit better in the AskUbuntu for the Emacs part.

Comment: Not AskUbuntu: Emacs works on all major OSes, and probably a surprising number of minor ones.

Comment: Now there is the [Emacs StackExchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little bug with RefTeX (AUCTeX without RefTeX works like a charm in this case), but you can workaround it easily: use a comma separated list of bibliography databases:

```
\bibliography{a,b}
```

instead of

```
\bibliography{a.bib}
\bibliography{b.bib}
```

Comment: Thanks! The workaround works with \bibliography. (but unfortunately \addbibresource does not accept a comma separated list of resources).

Comment: I've reported the bug to the AUCTeX mailing list.

Comment: @Marc the bug has been fixed in development version of Emacs, see [this diff](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/revision/114894)

Comment: @giordano does it work for you with *addbibresource*? I came across this issue and somehow I don't see the contents of the 2nd file with reftex even if `reftex-locate-bibliography-files` returns a few files http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231210/9162.

Comment: @mlt  I can't use Emacs 24.4 right now (here I have only Emacs 24.3 which is known to suffer from this bug, it has been fixed later), what I can tell you is that this is a problem with RefTeX, not AUCTeX, as I already said AUCTeX can find all bibliography entries and indeed autocompletion with `TAB` works in `C-c [`.  When I'll be able to test with Emacs 24.4 I'll give you more information.