# Problem with Reftex - how to get it to index bib for all files?

Tags: citing, emacs, auctex, reftex

#### edit : here's a screencast of the problem for me : https://vid.me/uBHN

I have cloned this project :

```
https://github.com/vermiculus/smppaper
```

I have then created a new file in the `sections` directory called `this.tex` as follows

```
\section{Further Work}
\label{sec:further-work}

There are many things that, due to the sheer time constraints of the project,
  have been left undone.
Some are tasks that I consider to be bugs or areas of severe lacking,
  but some are critical bugs of the interface that should be taken into account
  when using it.

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "../smp.tex"
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% reftex-cite-format: "\\autocite{%l}"
%%% TeX-command-default: "arara"
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

After including that file in the main `smp.tex`
[file](https://github.com/vermiculus/smppaper/blob/master/smp.tex) with
`\include{sections/this}` and saving both files i then try to run
`reftex-citation` and get the following error :

```
byte-code: No valid bibliography in this document, and no default available
```

I'm not sure why this is - and when I google for this error I get info about
Reftex not finding the bibliography.

This doesn't make sense as when I open a file such as
`smppaper/sections/further-work.tex` and run `refTeX-citation` I can see a list
of the possible bibTeX entries.

It seems as though there's some kind of compilation going on but I'm not sure
what this is, because it also seems that when I open a new file the citations
are complied on the fly, this is a paste of the message buffer :

```
Loading /smppaper/auto/smp.el (source)...done
Loading /smppaper/auto/smp.el (source)...done
Loading /smppaper/sections/auto/this.el (source)...done
Loading /smppaper/auto/this.el (source)...done
Applying style hooks... done
byte-code: Beginning of buffer
Compiling label environment definitions...done
Scanning entire document...
Scanning file /home/vco/vermy/smppaper/smp.tex
Scanning file abstract.txt
Scanning file sections/this
Scanning section 1 ...
Scanning file sections/introduction
Scanning section 2 ...
Scanning file sections/mathematical-representation
Scanning section 3 ...
Scanning file sections/logical-representation
Scanning section 4 ...
Scanning file sections/interface-test
Scanning section 5 ...
Scanning file sections/interface-ssa
Scanning section 6 ...
Scanning file sections/further-work
Scanning section 7 ...
Scanning file sections/reflection
Scanning section 8 ...
Scanning file appendices/bundle-format
Scanning section A ...
Scanning file appendices/gui-organization
Scanning section B ...
Scanning document... done
Sorting bibitem...
Removing duplicates... done
Quit
Mark set
```

I'm not sure what this is doing, but looking at the lines such as `Loading
/smppaper/sections/auto/this.el (source)...done` I thought they might be
interesting, but I can't see anything in there that's different. When I look
through `further-work.el` and compare it I can't see much difference.

#### further-work.el

```
(TeX-add-style-hook "further-work"
(lambda ()
    (LaTeX-add-labels
    "sec:further-work"
    "sec:tasks:bugs"
    "task:alg-aggr"
    "task:update-name"
    "task:test"
    "task:definition-newline"
    "task:valid-pred"
    "task:reliable-hl"
    "task:dates"
    "task:testing-interface"
    "task:interface"
    "task:gui-syntax-highlighting"
    "task:gui-definition-wrapping"
    "task:smarter-def"
    "task:temp-files"
    "sec:tasks:ext"
    "tast:autodate"
    "task:gephi-glue"
    "task:anigexf"
    "task:gui-visualizer"
    "task:texport"
    "task:bundle-graphs"
    "task:save-history"
    "task:arbitrary-attributes"
    "task:magical-references"
    "task:stackless"
    "task:genetic")))
```

#### this.el

```
(TeX-add-style-hook
"this"
(lambda ()
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "lstlisting")
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "path")
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "url")
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "nolinkurl")
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "hyperbaseurl")
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "hyperimage")
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "hyperref")
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "lstinline")
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local "path")
  (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local "lstinline")
  (LaTeX-add-labels
    "sec:further-work"))
:latex)
```

---

They  don't seem to have anything that that (to me) relates to Reftex?

So I'm not sure what's happening or how to sort this.

Comment: Have you considered asking on the auctex mailinglist (it might also be them who is maintaining reftex), https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/mailing-lists.html

Comment: I could I'd be amazed if there isn't a simple solution to this though. I expect this is something I'm not understanding rather than something wrong with software

Comment: As David said in the chat, there might not be that many reftex users on the site. I use it a lot for editing, but I rarely cite something (already don in the docs I edit). First of I'd test if everything works if all files are in the same dir.

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using? This may be a bug; see the comments here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141213/8528

Comment: Im using : `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8)`.
But the thing is it **works** when I try using it from a file that's already in
the project. It doesn't work when i try it on a file that I've added to the
project. @jon

Comment: @baxx - Try this: Delete your `this.tex`, put `(setq-default TeX-master nil)` in your `.emacs` and restart Emacs, `C-x C-f` a new file `this.tex` and in Minibuffer, enter the path to `smp.tex`.  Check the result with `C-h v LaTeX-bibliography-list RET`.

Comment: @Johannes_B yeh cheers :)

Comment: @ArashEsbati I'll try that - i've just removed latex and reinstalled from tug rather than using ubuntu repo, not sure if this will do anything or not. cheers